# Automatically Combine/Bundle EF Migration(s)

Tags: entity-framework, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, webdeploy

I'm wondering if it is possible to run some automated tasks either on a **Release** (web deploy) action, or **Branch Merge** (TFS) action?

Ideally I would like to set up a process that will automatically combine EF migrations since *the last release*. I'm still looking into how I would automate this, but I think the first step is hooking into a suitable event.

I haven't setup a build server yet, but I'm guessing if the above isn't possible then this would be an option for attaching a custom procedure to the MSBuild task?

Alternatively, if anyone has experience in automating things like this I would be happy to hear it. I am the head of development at a web development company and I would like to facilitate our current processes by automating some of our standard procedures, and this is something we do over any over again for each development!

I appreciate your time looking at my question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

VSTS and TFS2015 both support a CI/CD process via their new build and release system.  Very flexible and powerful.  Check it out!

https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Release/getting-started/understand-rm

VS/WebDeploy does support deploying EF migrations with a web application:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#efcfmigrations

This works fine for deploying a small application/system but when you want to deploy a larger system with many components it doesn't work as well.  We create MSDeploy packages for each component of the system.  For example, this is how we deploy SQL databases:

http://dotnetcatch.chief7.space/2016/02/10/deploying-a-database-project-with-msdeploy/